# force SSL for single .html page without php or anything else just using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

After several hours of trying a myriad of suggestions for .htaccess I have given up and decided to ask here.

I have a single html page that needs to be served via SSL. It is a single file with the .htm extension and it contains no php whatsoever. If anybody accesses this page via typing it in or clicking on a link from a non SSL page, I want that person to be redirected to or shown the SSL version of that page. Only https://example.com/myfile.htm should be allowed. The rest of the site can go without SSL, just this one page needs it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
    RewriteRule ^myfile\.htm$ https://www.example.com/myfile.htm [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your suggestion sends my page into a redirect loop. :-(

Comment: Give this a try. Also if you don't have all the links on that page pointing to https, you are going to get insecure message warnings.

Comment: "This webpage has a redirect loop" :-(

Comment: This didn't send the page into a redirect loop but suffers from the same consequences like Jon Lin's suggestion. Breaks the page and the entire site if I navigate away from the page.

Comment: How is your js and css being loaded? That shouldn't have anything to do with the redirect.

Comment: The thing is, when I just type in the URL with https everything works fine, I get no errors, I can wander around the site without any problems. So all js/css is setup correctly, tested this thoroughly.

Comment: Never mind, there was some other stuff buried in this .htaccess file that was messing with your answer. It's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^myfile\.htm$  https://example.com/myfile.htm [L,R]
```

Comment: This worked but broke the page and spits out all sorts of security warnings about unsecure content being loaded, also breaks the rest of the site when navigating away from the page.

Comment: @Flobbo do you have an SSL certificate for "example.com"?

Comment: Yes I do. When I access the secure connection by typing it in directly, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**SSL for HTML only page / SSL for JavaScript only page:**
If anyone needs to set SSL (HTTPS) for page that uses html only (without PHP, nodeJS etc.) just put .htaccess file in the same folder as index.htm page.
Content of the .htaccess have to be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I had trouble finding how to, so I think that this thread is the best to hold this answer.